# sed unknown option to 's'

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am attempting to write a short bash script that removes CSS comments from a file (so any text including and in between /* and */), however it needs to ignore lines that have the string "not" or "NOT" in it.

This is what I've got so far:

```
sed '\_(not|NOT)_!s_/\*_,_\*/_g' $1
```

However, when running the script, it is returning with the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown option to `s'
```

My first assumption was that using forward slashes was causing issues, despite escaping the characters, so I used underscores as the delimiters instead. However, that has not resolved my issue.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: This isn't what you asked, but if you're actual goal is to minify/compress CSS, there are tools for that.

Comment: Underscores are reasonably common chars, just like `/` chars. Can you use one of `#@~|` instead? Also, not all seds require (or understand) an escaped initial delimiter like `\_`. Did you try it without the leading backslash? Good luck.

Comment: `s_/\*_,_\*/_g` have too much separator (`_` here) and is maybe (i guess) something like `s#/\*#,_\*/#g`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the part up to the ! but the syntax for s is `s_old_new_` optionally followed by some options.

You have a , and an extra _ in there. Or maybe you meant `s_/\*.*/\*__g` to replace comments with nothing.

Recommendation: Build it up in tiny pieces. Eg try just stripping out sequences of letters, test that, then add the feature to skip "not" lines, then make it strip comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with this:

```
sed -e '/not /I!s/\/\*.*\*\///g' $1
```

Found out about the case insensitive flag that you can use, which picks up both "not" and "NOT". I also figured out the correct syntax for finding all comments and replacing with nothing.

Thanks to everyone for their help.